# Is there an equivalent for xml.etree.ElementTree module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, libxml2

I'm parsing a bunch of XML elements just fine, using the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import requests
import pandas_gbq
import xml.etree.ElementTree
REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.corporate-site/report-api/?obj_device=47116&Yesterday'
response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=(login, password))
xml_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore') 

root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(xml_data)

desc = root.get("Description")
```

The code above works perfectly fine in my client-side Python 3.6 setup.  I'm having a big problem moving this into a Google Cloud Function, because apparently Google doesn't recognize this xml.etree.ElementTree module.  Has anyone here used Google Cloud Functions?  If so, is there a way to get the remote, server-side, environment setup to match a local environment?  Or, is there an equivalent of the xml.etree.ElementTree module, which does a good job of parsing XML syntax?  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the [System Packages list](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/python-system-packages) what are the current supported packages in the Python3 runtime, for Cloud Functions.

Doing a quick search, seems that the only supported module related to XML is `libxml2`. You can check the documentation of this library [here](http://xmlsoft.org/). As well can check how this library's Python binding works [in this examples](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html).

As well, if this library it's not enough for the usage you want to make out of your Cloud Function, you can issue a Feature Request in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559729) to ask for the implementation of your requested libraries. This is the [direct link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=1163154) to create a new Feature Request.